# SQL Full Text Not Installed

Tags: sql-server

I am doing some full text stuff in a database and keep getting this error message back. Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded. The full text search is installed and the service is running. I have also run a query in the db to see if it is installed and it say 0 (no). I am using sql server 2005 and windows server 2003. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Hi I gone and done that and can not see the reg value so I wlll have a crack at install it now.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing this query.

select fulltextserviceproperty('isfulltextinstalled')

If SQL returning a 0 means the service is not installed.

or

Could you please check the following registry path for SQL Server 2005 default instance,

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSearch\GlobalAdminBlob

Is there a key named Blob0?

The key indicates the Full Text Search

If not installed, stop all currently installed services and try to reinstall fulltext seratch.